# Booking Table using integrity enhancement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to solve a question but I am stuck at a point.Below are the given from. I am trying to create the Booking table using integrity enhancement but in the constraints the same room can not be double booked.

Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city) Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price) Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress) where Hotel contains hotel details and hotelNo is the primary key. Room contains room details for each hotel and (roomNo, hoteINo) forms the primary key. Booking contains details of bookings and (hoteINo, guestNo, dateFrom) forms the primary key. Guest contains guest details and guestNo is the primary key..

Here is how far I have gone:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
    hotelNo     HotelNumbers        NOT NULL,
    guestNo GuestNumbers        NOT NULL,
    dateFrom    BookingDate     NOT NULL,
    dateTo      BookingDate     NULL,
    roomNo      RoomNumber      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom),
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES Hotel 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (guestNo) REFERENCES Guest 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo, roomNo) REFERENCES Room
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT RoomBooked
    CHECK (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM Booking b
                WHERE b.dateTo > Booking.dateFrom AND
                b.dateFrom < Booking.dateTo AND
                b.roomNo = Booking.roomNo AND
                b.hotelNo = Booking.hotelNo)),
    CONSTRAINT GuestBooked
    CHECK (NOT EXISTS ( ...............)
```

Comment: Is this even allowed - having subqueries in the check constraints? I know SQL Server doesn't allows it, not sure about MySQL. However, I would suggest keeping the Data Integrity constraints either at the Application Layer or if you want to keep it at the DB level, then apply them through database triggers where you can handle the transactions and error messages better.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need pk on Booking from 4 fields: hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, roomNo; and you must modify CONSTRAINT RoomBooked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
hotelNo     HotelNumbers        NOT NULL,
guestNo GuestNumbers        NOT NULL,
dateFrom    BookingDate     NOT NULL,
dateTo      BookingDate     NULL,
roomNo      RoomNumber      NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, roomNo),
FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES Hotel 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (guestNo) REFERENCES Guest 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo, roomNo) REFERENCES Room
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT RoomBooked
CHECK (NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT 1
 FROM Booking b
 WHERE (
  isnull(b.dateTo, b.dateFrom) 
   between Booking.dateFrom and isnull(Booking.dateTo, Booking.dateFrom)
  or b.dateFrom 
   between Booking.dateFrom and isnull(Booking.dateTo, Booking.dateFrom))
 AND b.roomNo = Booking.roomNo 
 AND b.hotelNo = Booking.hotelNo)))
```

and i'm think, one guest can book more then one room so you can't set CONSTRAINT for GuestBooked